# Azure Tools for VS - can't sign in to subscription

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a pretty strange issue with Azure tools for VS 2013 (version 2.6). Whenever I try to sign in to my Azure subscription (e.g. from Server explorer or creating a new web role project) I get the following error:

---

### Server Explorer

### An error occurred during the sign in process: User 'foo@gmail.com' returned by service does not match user 'bar@outlook.com' in the request

### OK

My subscription owned by 'bar@outlook.com' and I can perfectly fine sign in either to management portal in a browser (IE, Spartan and Chrome) - as well as in the Power Shell. Tried everything - cleaning up browser caches/cookies, resetting IE settings, playing with different IE security settings - nothign works.

Any help is appreciated - this issue drives me crazy.

P.S. I'm on Windows 10...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Imported the certificate manually and everything worked ok: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9cdafeb4-f459-436d-b2b8-9bc5c01f0df1/azure-tools-for-vs-cant-sign-in-to-subscription?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

Comment: Please add the relevant details from the link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, to resolve it I:

- Added 'foo@gmail.com' as an alias in my 'bar@outlook.com' Microsoft account, via [account.live.com](https://account.live.com/names/Manage?mkt=en-US)
- Made the 'foo@gmail.com' email address the primary alias for my Microsoft account

I could then log in successfully in to Azure by pressing the Connect to Microsoft Azure button in the toolbar of the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013 and see all of my websites under the App Service node.

(When I'd used the certificate method described in the other post and Microsoft documentation I'd been able to see all my sql databases etc. but not the websites.)

Once I'd done all that I then switched my primary alias back to 'bar@outlook.com' and server explorer carried on working.

NB: If you're experimenting with this beware that there is a limit on how many times you can switch your primary.. as I have just discovered.. and now my primary is stuck on the wrong email address for a week.

NB2:  If your connecting in order to be able to remote debug the website, then this can still be done by going to Visual Studio>Main Menu>Debug>Attach To Process, and then enter the URL of the site (without the http bit, e.g. mysite.azurewebsites.net) as the Qualifier and then attach to the w3wp.exe process.

Comment: Your point about the remote debugging was useful, thank you for adding that. I wasn't able to login though, do you know what credentials to use? The deployment/FTP ones did not work.

Comment: "When you're prompted for credentials, enter the user name and password that has permissions to deploy content to the web app. To get these credentials, go to the Dashboard tab for your web app in the management portal and click Download the publish profile. Open the file in a text editor, and you'll find the user name and password after the first occurrences of userName= and userPWD=. ".  From this excellent article on getting it all working: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue. It seems that the Azure sign-in in Visual Studio is redirecting to our organizational Single Sign-On instead of the Microsoft one. I have managed to work around this problem by using a Microsoft account that is not tied to my organization:

1. Create new Microsoft account or use an existing account not associated with your organization
2. In https://manage.windowsazure.com select Subscriptions/Manage Administrators
3. Choose Add+ and add the new Microsoft account as administrator to your subscription
4. Log on to Azure using the new account from Visual Studio

/Morten

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Microsoft account's email address and had this problem. Adding an alias did not help.

The problem is to do with the [Azure Active Directory Library for DotNet](http://azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet). For whatever dumb reason, they throw an exception when Azure returns an ID different than the one requested (if the server isn't crying about it, why make up an error and make the client deal with it?).

Since Azures's support was no help, I had to build a custom copy of the ADAL with that moronic exception removed and an assembly version matching the one used in VS2013 (2.11). Also importantly, disable strong name verification for the custom assembly.